# How can I get automatic unique atomic counter binding points (no hard coded binding=)?

Tags: opengl, glsl, modularity, hardcoded

Many articles describe using atomic counters by specifying a fixed binding point:

```
//Shader:
layout(binding = 0, offset = 0) uniform atomic_uint myAtomicCounter;

//App code
glBindBufferBase(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, myBufferHandle);
```

Here, the hard coded binding point `binding = 0` is specified in both the shader and application code. I guess these articles do it this way because,

> Atomic counters are not assigned a location and may not be
>   modified using the `Uniform*` commands. The bindings,
>   offsets, and strides belonging to atomic counters
>   of a program object are invalidated and new ones
>   assigned after each successful re-link. <sup>[[shader_atomic_counters]](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_atomic_counters.txt)</sup>

The above is fine until you want some more modular shader code. For example I have two shader include files, each needing an atomic counter that I've written as pluggable code that doesn't know about the other. Clearly I don't want to specify hard coded binding points and I'd like the application to handle it automatically. I don't really care which binding points they use, just that they aren't the same.

Vertex shader attributes appear similar. I can force a binding location at runtime (`glBindAttribLocation`) before shader linking or alternatively let OpenGL choose them for me and then query the result (`glGetAttribLocation`). I can also search through all attributes (`glGetActiveAttrib`).

**How can I implement automatic unique binding points for atomic counters, so they're not hard coded and I can mix shader code?**

I can see a few ways this might be possible, still with the limitation of not changing them after linking:

1. Don't specify the binding point in the shader and let OpenGL pick one when linking. I don't know if OpenGL will do this. If it does, **how do you query to find the binding point used?**
2. Query the shader objects before linking to find atomic counters. Then give them unique binding locations just like `glBindAttribLocation` for attributes. **Is there a mechanism to assign binding points?**
3. Parse all the shader code, looking for atomic counters and replace the binding points with unique indices in the shader code itself, perhaps using `#define` macros. A last resort. I really don't want to have to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On point 1: The `binding` layout parameter for atomic counters is *not optional*.

On point 2: Because `binding` is not optional, there's no point in being able to set it from OpenGL code.

So your only recourse is #3.

Answer (score 1):

You can query for atomic counters using `glGetActiveUniform`. Then get the buffer index and finally the binding point:

```
int atomicCounterIndex;
glGetActiveUniformsiv(programId, count, index, 
        GL_UNIFORM_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER_INDEX, &atomicCounterIndex);
glGetActiveAtomicCounterBufferiv(programId, atomicCounterIndex, 
        GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER_BINDING, &myBufferHandle)
```

This works since OpenGL 4.2 as stated [in the docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetActiveUniformsiv.xhtml)